# I cannot print the fcm localization variable

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I am throwing fcm bulk notifications. but notifications do not go localized. I cannot use the username versin that I send in the data.
My notifications go as follows;
%1$s joined. Send first message!
but it should be;
Username joined. Send first message!

somehow I couldn't get the variable I sent... even if I set the usrname variable inside the application, it doesn't show up.

No notification when sending body_loc_args

```
            case GCM_NOTIFY_NEWUSER: {

                if (App.getInstance().getId() != 0 && Long.toString(App.getInstance().getId()).equals(accountId)) {

                    App.getInstance().setNotificationsCount(App.getInstance().getNotificationsCount() + 1);
                    Uri profile_like = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.profile_liken);
                    //message = context.getString(R.string.label_newuser_notify, newusername);
                    String yuzir = "TEST";
                    String new_user = context.getString(R.string.label_newuser_notify, yuzir);
                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_push_notification)
                                    .setContentTitle(title)
                                    .setSound(profile_like)
                                    .setContentText(new_user);

                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    resultIntent.putExtra("pageId", PAGE_NOTIFICATIONS);
                    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

                    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
                    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
                    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, flag);
                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                                .build();
                        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

                        mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
                        mChannel.setSound(profile_like, audioAttributes);
                        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                    }

                    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
                    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
                }

                break;
            }
```

```
        $notify = array("priority" => "high", "image" => $this->data['image'], "body_loc_key" => "label_newuser_notify", "yuzir"=> $this->data['newusername']); //body_loc_args gönderince bildirim gelmiyor
        //$notify = array("priority" => "high", "image" => $this->data['image'], "newusername" => $this->data['newusername'], "body" => "label_newuser_notify");
        

                $post = array(
            'registration_ids'  => $this->ids,
            'data'              => $notify,
            'aps'               => array("content_available" => "true"),
            'notification'      => array("content_available" => "true")
        );
```

I have tried almost everything. I have been trying for weeks and I could not send it with this variable.